# How to subset Pandas dataframe based on column's name using dynamic value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, streamlit

So I develop a streamlit program which supposedly can subset a pandas dataframes based on value I pick from selectbox. I have difficulty to produce a new dataframe using value from the selectbox

The main dataframe have structure like this:

| PROVINCE | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 2 |
| bbb | 2 | 3 |

And this one is the script for the selectbox:

```
list_year= df.columns.values.tolist()
year_select = st.selectbox('Year',list_year)
```

the result I expect to have when I select year "2022" from selectbox can produce a dataframe with this structure:

| PROVINCE | 2022 |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 |
| bbb | 2 |

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "PROVINCE" is a column, just slice with:

```
out = df[['PROVINCE', year_select]]
```

Comment: works like charm! don't expect the solution as simple as this :'(

Answer (score 1):

Assume `PROVINCE` is the index of your dataframe:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

def filter_dataframe(df):
    list_year = df.columns.values.tolist()
    year_select = st.selectbox('Year', list_year, index=None)
    return df[year_select] if year_select else df

data = {'PROVINCE': ['aaa', 'bbb'],
        '2022': [1, 2],  # Note '2022' is a string not a numeric
        '2023': [2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('PROVINCE')
st.dataframe(filter_dataframe(df))
```

Output:

[image]

[image]